# Keep getting AttibuteError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateLayer'

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal

I want to create a shapefile. Here is my code:

```
import ogr, sys, os
import osgeo.osr as osr

line=ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
line.AddPoint(10,10)
line.AddPoint(20,20)

driver=ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds=driver.CreateDataSource('test.shp')

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

layer=ds.CreateLayer('test', srs, ogr.wkbLineString)
fieldDefn_=ogr.FieldDefn('id', ogr.OFTInteger)
layer.CreateField(fieldDefn_)
featureDefn=layer.GetLayerDefn()
feature=ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
feature.SetGeometry(line)
feature.SetField('id',1)
layer.CreateFeature(feature)
```

but when I run the code no shapefile appears on my desktop like I was thinking. It instead says on my console:

```
AttibuteError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateLayer'
```

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: Looks like your `ds` object wasn't properly created? This `'NoneType'` seems strange...

Comment: @Rodrigo just to be sure here, the idea is that a shapefile 'test.shp' will be created on my desktop once this script runs, right? just want to make sure I understand the output.

Comment: @Rodrigo so for some reason or another the line: shapeData = driver.CreateDataSource('grid.shp') just isn't working. Because that is why it says no attribute 'CreateLayer'? It is acting on 'grid.shp' but it's not responding.

Comment: "the idea is that a shapefile 'test.shp' will be created on my desktop once this script runs" - I think so, but I don't use Java anymore. You'll have to debug, and see what this object `ds` contains after you try to create it.